# Flutter Firebase: How to implement and structure your data replies comment just like other Social medial

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i am building an app that deals with forums and community.. i am stuck on creating a replies and structuring that data in firebase.

while posting or commenting, i give each every user a list of reply,
the code:

```
communityPageComment(String comment, Map comId) async {
  final userdata =
      await firestore.collection('user').doc(auth.currentUser!.uid).get();
  final userinfo = userdata.data();
  firestore
      .collection('comment')
      .doc(comId['id'])
      .collection('ForumComment')
      .doc()
      .set({
    'name': userinfo!['name'],
    'image': userinfo['picture'],
    'timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    'text': comment,
    'reply': []// here will be where all the replies of this post will be in Map...
  });
}
```

which is working fine..

let assume Mr. UserA post... After Mr. userA posting and another user, Mr b reply to mr A...

which will be append to the `List of map` which the **code is this**.

```
replyToComment(String comment, Map comId) async {
  final userdata =
      await firestore.collection('user').doc(auth.currentUser!.uid).get();
  final userinfo = userdata.data();

  Map data = {
    'name': userinfo!['name'],
    'image': userinfo['picture'],
    'text': comment,
    'reply':[]

  };
  
  firestore
      .collection('comment')
      .doc(comId['id'])
      .collection('ForumComment')
      .doc()
      .update({'reply': FieldValue.arrayUnion([data])});
}
```

this is fine...

**where my problem start**

if another user want to reply Mr B which is Mr C.

how can i target base on the index to Mr B comment programmingly using the **replyToComment Function i created about**..

Thanks

Comment: Hey, did you find a way to do this ?

Comment: no, i use another logic, which is: if mr c click on reply it will just put the name of the user with @..